# how long can I build a successful face recognize system?

Tags: face-recognition

My boss want me to build a face recognize system with the accuracy is 80% or more. Maybe our system have  a thousand people. I'm using C# and I have some questions that I want to ask you:

1) Can I successfully build the system like this?

2)What is the most effective method (maybe need the combination)?

3) How long will I spend to finish this system?

Please help me. Thank you so much.

I'm not good at English. So If something is wrong. Please let me know. I will fix my sentences.

**EDIT 1:**

I already built my own face recognize system and the accuracy was not good. The following is what I have done:

1) Face Detection.

2) Detect Gender.

3) Detect Age Range.

4) Face Recognize. (* - Fisher face recognition OpenCV)

I don't care about 1), 2), and 3) because I have done them successfully.

We now have problem with (*). It's very complicated that we have many cameras all over America and we use them to capture faces and then detect face, detect gender, detect age range and finally recognize face.

Of course, we always have the input of the face recognize is a face image which we have after detecting face from captured picture. To get more accuracy, I only detect the face without no pan and tilt (frontal faces with approximately 0 degree, I have done it too).

Because the result was not good. So I think that I need another method to implement this. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, but it depends on your skills;
2) I think [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) has some algorithms for that;
3) log 3N * (N**3 / q - P**8). Where P is how fast you press one button on keyboard (km/h);

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of good open source facial recognition systems out there already. Do you have to build your own?

I would recommend looking at some resources like [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) or [OpenBR](http://openbiometrics.org/)

You could build your own system, but it would be fairly difficult to do in a short period of time and would be a bad reinvention of the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Face Recognizition Simple way to implement for a Beginner

[image]

1) Here successfully predict the name of the player  
2) Tools to be used google cloud platform (https://colab.research.google.com/)
3) required certain images for the training 
4) make a directory inside sample_data called images
5) copy all the images into images folder 
6) Download the source code from here,
https://github.com/Rizwan54/face-recognizition-example

here is your turn to implement,

```
pip install face_recognition
import face_recognition
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import os

# make a list of all the available images
images = os.listdir('sample_data/images')

known_face_encodings = []

# iterate over each image
for image in images:

   # load the image
   current_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("sample_data/images/" + image)

   # encode the loaded image into a feature vector
   current_image_encoded = face_recognition.face_encodings(current_image)[0]

   #append the all the encode images into a list
   known_face_encodings.append(current_image_encoded)



# Load an image with an unknown face
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("sample_data/jadeja_p.png")

# Find all the faces and face encodings in the unknown image
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(unknown_image)
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image, face_locations)


# Convert the image to a PIL-format image so that we can draw on top of it with the 
Pillow library
# See http://pillow.readthedocs.io/ for more about PIL/Pillow
pil_image = Image.fromarray(unknown_image)

# Create a Pillow ImageDraw Draw instance to draw with
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)

# Loop through each face found in the unknown image
for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):

   # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
   matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

   name = "unknown"

   # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
   # if True in matches:
   #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
   #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

   # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
   face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, 
   face_encoding)
   best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
   if matches[best_match_index]:
       name = images[best_match_index]

   # Draw a box around the face using the Pillow module
   draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=(0, 0, 255))

   # Draw a label with a name below the face
   text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(name)
   draw.rectangle(((left, bottom - text_height - 10), (right, bottom)), fill=(0, 0, 
   255), outline=(0, 0, 255))
   draw.text((left + 6, bottom - text_height - 5), name, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

   # Remove the drawing library from memory as per the Pillow docs
   del draw

    # Display the resulting image
    pil_image.show()

    # You can also save a copy of the new image to disk if you want by uncommenting 
    this line
    pil_image.save("jadeja_p.png")
```